# Trying to find what I need to look up and research. What kind a query do we need? We are using a CTE. Do we need recursive?

Tags: sql, loops, recursion, reporting-services, common-table-expression

Drug screen results for student lab.

The section for this report shows all positives for the patient for the last 5 drug tests they have done.  This section should display for any positive encountered in the last five test the results if they are positive and negative until such time as the test is negative 4 times then it should drop off.

We are using a CTE to grab the last 5 tests but are struggling to get the section with four negatives to drop off.

Help!  Please I don't know what to search for to try and write this!

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY rq.requisitionKey DESC) AS  'RN',
    rq.requisitionKey,
    COALESCE(CONVERT(XML,'<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result ,'***',']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[1]','varchar(25)'),'') AS [Numeric],
    COALESCE(CONVERT(XML,'<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result ,'***',']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[2]','varchar(75)'),'') AS [Text],
    COALESCE(CONVERT(XML,'<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result ,'***',']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[3]','varchar(25)'),'') AS [Threshold],
    FORMAT(CONVERT(date, sv.EpochToLocal(rq.createStamp)), 'MM/dd/yyyy') 'OrderDate',
    t.name,
    pnl.reportGroup,
    t.testKey,
    r.result,
    r.resultKey
FROM sv.requisition rq
JOIN sv.result r ON r.requisitionKey=rq.requisitionKey AND valueToReport=1
JOIN sv.test t ON r.testkey = t.testkey
JOIN sv.orderedpanel op ON r.orderedpanelkey = op.orderedpanelkey
JOIN sv.Panel pnl ON op.panelKey = pnl.panelKey
JOIN sv.ReportGroup rg ON pnl.reportGroup = rg.reportGroupKey
JOIN sv.patient p ON rq.patientkey = p.patientkey
WHERE p.patientKey = @VAR2
AND rq.canceledstamp < 0
AND rq.finaldeliverystamp > 0
AND rq.requisitionKey <=@VAR1
AND pnl.reportGroup=6
AND t.testKey IN (SELECT 
t.testKey
FROM sv.requisition rq
JOIN sv.result r ON r.requisitionKey=rq.requisitionKey
JOIN sv.test t ON t.testKey=r.testKey
WHERE rq.requisitionKey=@VAR1
AND valueToReport=1

/*AND (COALESCE(CONVERT(XML,'<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result ,'***',']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[3]','varchar(25)'),'')='Positive'
    OR COALESCE(CONVERT(XML,'<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result ,'***',']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[3]','varchar(25)'),'') LIKE '>%')*/
))

SELECT 
    CTE.RN,
    CTE.name,
    CTE.Result,
    CTE.resultKey,
    CTE.Numeric,
    CTE.Threshold,
    CTE.Text,
    CTE.OrderDate,
    CTE.requisitionKey
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.RN<5 AND (CTE.Threshold = 'Positive' OR CTE.Threshold LIKE '>%')
ORDER BY CTE.RN
```

So we wrote another CTE to try and correct that.  Below.  Only this one shows positives and negatives even if there was never a positive result for the test.

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY rq.requisitionKey DESC
            ) AS 'RN'
        ,rq.requisitionKey
        ,COALESCE(CONVERT(XML, '<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result, '***', ']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[1]', 'varchar(25)'), '') AS [Numeric]
        ,COALESCE(CONVERT(XML, '<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result, '***', ']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[2]', 'varchar(75)'), '') AS [Text]
        ,COALESCE(CONVERT(XML, '<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result, '***', ']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[3]', 'varchar(25)'), '') AS [Threshold]
        ,FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE, sv.EpochToLocal(rq.createStamp)), 'MM/dd/yyyy') 'OrderDate'
        ,t.name
        ,pnl.reportGroup
        ,t.testKey
        ,r.result
        ,r.resultKey
    FROM sv.requisition rq
    JOIN sv.result r ON r.requisitionKey = rq.requisitionKey
        AND valueToReport = 1
    JOIN sv.test t ON r.testkey = t.testkey
    JOIN sv.orderedpanel op ON r.orderedpanelkey = op.orderedpanelkey
    JOIN sv.Panel pnl ON op.panelKey = pnl.panelKey
    JOIN sv.ReportGroup rg ON pnl.reportGroup = rg.reportGroupKey
    JOIN sv.patient p ON rq.patientkey = p.patientkey
    WHERE p.patientKey = @VAR2
        AND rq.canceledstamp < 0
        AND rq.finaldeliverystamp > 0
        AND rq.requisitionKey <= @VAR1
        AND pnl.reportGroup = 6
        AND r.valuetoReport = 1
    )
    ,SUBCTE
AS (
    SELECT name
        ,COUNT(threshold) 'NegCount'
    FROM CTE
    WHERE rn < 5
        AND threshold = 'Negative'
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(threshold) = 4
    )
SELECT CTE.RN
    ,CTE.name
    ,CTE.Result
    ,CTE.resultKey
    ,CTE.NUMERIC
    ,CTE.Threshold
    ,CTE.TEXT
    ,CTE.OrderDate
    ,CTE.requisitionKey
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.RN < 5
    AND CTE.Threshold <> ''
    
    AND CTE.name NOT IN (
        SELECT name
        FROM subCTE
        )
ORDER BY CTE.RN
```

Sample of result data

| RN | name | Result | resultKey | Numeric | Threshold | Text | OrderDate | requisitionKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amphetamine | 667.14***Inconsistent***Positive | 14132956 | 667.14 | Positive | Inconsistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | Buprenorphine | 38.64***Consistent***Positive | 14127690 | 38.64 | Positive | Consistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | Norbuprenorphine | 1420.26***Consistent***Positive | 14127691 | 1420.26 | Positive | Consistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | Nordiazepam | 87.05***Inconsistent***Positive | 14127697 | 87.05 | Positive | Inconsistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 | 1 | 14.19***Inconsistent***Positive | 14.19 | Inconsistent | 1441076 |
| 1 | Norfentanyl | 593.22***Inconsistent***>500 | 14127699 | 593.22 | >500 | Inconsistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | Methamphetamine | 1307.78***Inconsistent***Positive | 14132957 | 1307.78 | Positive | Inconsistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | Naloxone | 64.87***Consistent***Positive | 14127710 | 64.87 | Positive | Consistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | Oxazepam | 1467.79***Inconsistent***Positive | 14127713 | 1467.79 | Positive | Inconsistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | Temazepam | 174.40***Inconsistent***Positive | 14127719 | 174.40 | Positive | Inconsistent | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | Benzoylecgonine | 0.00******Negative | 14127692 | 0.00 | Negative |  | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 1 | D-Methamphetamine | 100******Positive | 14132955 | 100 | Positive |  | 04/27/2023 | 1441076 |
| 2 | D-Methamphetamine | 100******Positive | 13670635 | 100 | Positive |  | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Benzoylecgonine | 121.95***Inconsistent***Positive | 13644760 | 121.95 | Positive | Inconsistent | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Temazepam | 5.91******Negative | 13644787 | 5.91 | Negative |  | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Oxazepam | 9.89******Negative | 13644781 | 9.89 | Negative |  | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Naloxone | 127.96***Consistent***Positive | 13644778 | 127.96 | Positive | Consistent | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Methamphetamine | 7883.47***Inconsistent***>5000 | 13670637 | 7883.47 | >5000 | Inconsistent | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Norfentanyl | 294.75***Inconsistent***Positive | 13644767 | 294.75 | Positive | Inconsistent | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Fentanyl | 33.30***Inconsistent***Positive | 13644766 | 33.30 | Positive | Inconsistent | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Nordiazepam | 0.00******Negative | 13644765 | 0.00 | Negative |  | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Norbuprenorphine | 318.28***Consistent***Positive | 13644759 | 318.28 | Positive | Consistent | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Amphetamine | 5001.00***Inconsistent***>5000 | 13670636 | 5001.00 | >5000 | Inconsistent | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 2 | Buprenorphine | 28.53***Consistent***Positive | 13644758 | 28.53 | Positive | Consistent | 03/30/2023 | 1429246 |
| 3 | Amphetamine | 381.52******Positive | 13560235 | 381.52 | Positive |  | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Buprenorphine | 130.27***Consistent***Positive | 13538075 | 130.27 | Positive | Consistent | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Norbuprenorphine | 301.70***Consistent***Positive | 13538076 | 301.70 | Positive | Consistent | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Nordiazepam | 16.81******Negative | 13538082 | 16.81 | Negative |  | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Fentanyl | 3.57***Inconsistent***Positive | 13538083 | 3.57 | Positive | Inconsistent | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Norfentanyl | 431.74***Inconsistent***Positive | 13538084 | 431.74 | Positive | Inconsistent | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Methamphetamine | 3201.46******Positive | 13560236 | 3201.46 | Positive |  | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Naloxone | 358.66***Consistent***Positive | 13538062 | 358.66 | Positive | Consistent | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Oxazepam | 281.92***Inconsistent***Positive | 13538065 | 281.92 | Positive | Inconsistent | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Temazepam | 52.08***Inconsistent***Positive | 13538071 | 52.08 | Positive | Inconsistent | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | Benzoylecgonine | 10.82******Negative | 13538077 | 10.82 | Negative |  | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 3 | D-Methamphetamine | 100******Positive | 13558949 | 100 | Positive |  | 03/23/2023 | 1426102 |
| 4 | Benzoylecgonine | 7.34******Negative | 13264730 | 7.34 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Temazepam | 5.48******Negative | 13264758 | 5.48 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Tramadol | 0.00******Negative | 13264722 | 0.00 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | o-desmethyl-cis-tramadol | 0.00******Negative | 13264723 | 0.00 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Oxazepam | 0.00******Negative | 13264752 | 0.00 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Naloxone | 964.11***Consistent***Positive | 13264749 | 964.11 | Positive | Consistent | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Methamphetamine | 7.01******Negative | 13264747 | 7.01 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Norfentanyl | 0.00******Negative | 13264737 | 0.00 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Fentanyl | 0.00******Negative | 13264736 | 0.00 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Nordiazepam | 0.00******Negative | 13264735 | 0.00 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Buprenorphine | 169.83***Consistent***Positive | 13264728 | 169.83 | Positive | Consistent | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Norbuprenorphine | 1398.89***Consistent***Positive | 13264729 | 1398.89 | Positive | Consistent | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |
| 4 | Amphetamine | 24.59******Negative | 13264727 | 24.59 | Negative |  | 03/09/2023 | 1419497 |

Minimal

```
    DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, RN VARCHAR(2), name VARCHAR(40) NULL,Result VARCHAR(50) NULL,resultKey VARCHAR(30),NUMERIC VARCHAR(30) NULL,
Threshold VARCHAR(30) NULL, Text VARCHAR(30) NULL, OrderDate VARCHAR(30) NULL, requisitionKey VARCHAR(30) );
INSERT INTO @tbl (RN,name, Result,resultKey,NUMERIC,Threshold,Text,OrderDate,requisitionKey) VALUES

('1','Amphetamine','667.14***Inconsistent***Positive','14132956','667.14','Positive','Inconsistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Buprenorphine','38.64***Consistent***Positive','14127690','38.64','Positive','Consistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Norbuprenorphine','1420.26***Consistent***Positive','14127691','1420.26','Positive','Consistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Nordiazepam','87.05***Inconsistent***Positive','14127697','87.05','Positive','Inconsistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Fentanyl','14.19***Inconsistent***Positive','14127698','14.19','Positive','Inconsistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Norfentanyl','593.22***Inconsistent***>500','14127699','593.22','>500','Inconsistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Methamphetamine','1307.78***Inconsistent***Positive','14132957','1307.78','Positive','Inconsistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Naloxone','64.87***Consistent***Positive','14127710','64.87','Positive','Consistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Oxazepam','1467.79***Inconsistent***Positive','14127713','1467.79','Positive','Inconsistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Temazepam','174.40***Inconsistent***Positive','14127719','174.40','Positive','Inconsistent','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','Benzoylecgonine','0.00******Negative','14127692','0.00','Negative','','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('1','D-Methamphetamine','100******Positive','14132955','100','Positive','','04/27/2023','1441076'),
('2','D-Methamphetamine','100******Positive','13670635','100','Positive ','','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Benzoylecgonine','121.95***Inconsistent***Positive','13644760','121.95','Positive','Inconsistent','03/30/2023','1429242'),
('2','Temazepam','5.91******Negative','13644787','5.91','Negative','','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Oxazepam','9.89******Negative','13644781','9.89','Negative','','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Naloxone','127.96***Consistent***Positive','13644778','127.96','Positive','Consistent','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Methamphetamine','7883.47***Inconsistent***>5000','13670637','7883.47','>5000','Inconsistent','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Norfentanyl','294.75***Inconsistent***Positive','13644767','294.75','Positive','Inconsistent','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Fentanyl','33.30***Inconsistent***Positive','13644766','33.30','Positive','Inconsistent','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Nordiazepam','0.00******Negative','13644765','0.00','Negative','','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Norbuprenorphine','318.28***Consistent***Positive','13644759','318.28','Positive','Consistent','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Amphetamine','5001.00***Inconsistent***>5000','13670636','5001.00','>5000','Inconsistent','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('2','Buprenorphine','28.53***Consistent***Positive','13644758','28.53','Positive','Consistent','03/30/2023','1429246'),
('3','Amphetamine','381.52******Positive','13560235','381.52','Positive','','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Buprenorphine','130.27***Consistent***Positive','13538075','130.27','Positive','Consistent','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Norbuprenorphine','301.70***Consistent***Positive','13538076','301.70','Positive','Consistent','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Nordiazepam','16.81******Negative','13538082','16.81','Negative','','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Fentanyl','3.57***Inconsistent***Positive','13538083','3.57','Positive','Inconsistent','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Norfentanyl','431.74***Inconsistent***Positive','13538084','431.74','Positive','Inconsistent','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Methamphetamine','3201.46******Positive','13560236','3201.46','Positive','','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Naloxone','358.66***Consistent***Positive','13538062','358.66','Positive','Consistent','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Oxazepam','281.92***Inconsistent***Positive','13538065','281.92','Positive','Inconsistent','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Temazepam','52.08***Inconsistent***Positive','13538071','52.08','Positive','Inconsistent','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','Benzoylecgonine','10.82******Negative','13538077','10.82','Negative','','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('3','D-Methamphetamine','100******Positive','13558949','100','Positive','','03/23/2023','1426102'),
('4','Benzoylecgonine','7.34******Negative','13264730','7.34','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Temazepam','5.48******Negative','13264758','5.48','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Tramadol','0.00******Negative','13264722','0.00','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','o-desmethyl-cis-tramadol','0.00******Negative','13264723','0.00','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Oxazepam','0.00******Negative','13264752','0.00','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Naloxone','964.11***Consistent***Positive','13264749','964.11','Positive','Consistent','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Methamphetamine','7.01******Negative','13264747','7.01','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Norfentanyl','0.00******Negative','13264737','0.00','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Fentanyl','0.00******Negative','13264736','0.00','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Nordiazepam','0.00******Negative','13264735','0.00','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Buprenorphine','169.83***Consistent***Positive','13264728','169.83','Positive','Consistent','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Norbuprenorphine','1398.89***Consistent***Positive','13264729','1398.89','Positive','Consistent','03/09/2023','1419497'),
('4','Amphetamine','24.59******Negative','13264727','24.59','Negative','','03/09/2023','1419497');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: ... and format your data as tables so it is readable

Comment: @NickW it only wanted to put that in as a photo wouldn't keep the table formatting.  How do i do that?

Comment: For future reference, never use images on Stackoverflow - always use editable text as then someone can copy your data/code if they want to try a solution. This link shows you how to format tables: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables

Comment: You need a newline/carriage return before the start of the table

Comment: This is a bug with Stack Overflow they simply won't fix, the table appears correct when editing the question but needs the new line only when saved.

Comment: ok, I am fixing this and trying to create a minimal reproducible example ...give me a few.  what's with all the down votes, hasn't anyone ever been a new user to stack overflow here sheeze

Comment: @Tami, I too find it a bit unfair.

Comment: @NickW it was formatting as a table now its not, I broke it somehow.  tried carriage return did not fix it??

Comment: When editing, highlight the sample data and click `{}`.

Comment: @jarlh Ok I think I have put in a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Solved our own issue.

```
`WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY rq.requisitionKey DESC
            ) AS 'RN'
        ,rq.requisitionKey
        ,COALESCE(CONVERT(XML, '<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result, '***', ']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[1]', 'varchar(25)'), '') AS [Numeric]
        ,COALESCE(CONVERT(XML, '<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result, '***', ']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[2]', 'varchar(75)'), '') AS [Text]
        ,COALESCE(CONVERT(XML, '<root><part><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(r.result, '***', ']]></part><part><![CDATA[') + ']]></part></root>').value('/root[1]/part[3]', 'varchar(25)'), '') AS [Threshold]
        ,FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE, sv.EpochToLocal(rq.createStamp)), 'MM/dd/yyyy') 'OrderDate'
        ,t.name
        ,pnl.reportGroup
        ,t.testKey
        ,r.result
        ,r.resultKey
    FROM sv.requisition rq
    JOIN sv.result r ON r.requisitionKey = rq.requisitionKey
        AND valueToReport = 1
    JOIN sv.test t ON r.testkey = t.testkey
    JOIN sv.orderedpanel op ON r.orderedpanelkey = op.orderedpanelkey
    JOIN sv.Panel pnl ON op.panelKey = pnl.panelKey
    JOIN sv.ReportGroup rg ON pnl.reportGroup = rg.reportGroupKey
    JOIN sv.patient p ON rq.patientkey = p.patientkey
    WHERE p.patientKey = @VAR2
        AND rq.canceledstamp < 0
        AND rq.finaldeliverystamp > 0
        AND rq.requisitionKey < @VAR1
        AND pnl.reportGroup = 6
        AND r.valuetoReport = 1
    )
    ,SUBCTE
AS (
    SELECT name
        ,COUNT(threshold) 'NegCount'
    FROM CTE
    WHERE rn < 5
        AND threshold <> 'Negative'
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(threshold) >0
    )
SELECT CTE.RN
    ,CTE.name
    ,CTE.Result
    ,CTE.resultKey
    ,CTE.NUMERIC
    ,CTE.Threshold
    ,CTE.TEXT
    ,CTE.OrderDate
    ,CTE.requisitionKey
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.RN < 5
    AND CTE.Threshold <> ''
    AND CTE.name IN (
        SELECT name
        FROM subCTE
        )
ORDER BY CTE.RN
`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).